# What was the engine fault in Excession?

Tags: the-culture

> The cruiser spent another two days around the Esperi system and then broke away. It returned to the habitat called Tier with a trivial but niggling engine fault.

> ~ The Furious Purpose is one of a couple of Affronter craft that left Tier at the same time the fleet did; it could have been following the Peace Makes Plenty, the Sober Counsel told the Culture ship. ~ It is certainly the ship that returned to Tier… thirty-six days after whatever happened here.
>   ~ That's a little slow, the Fate sent. ~ According to my records a meteorite-class light cruiser should have been able to do it in… oh, wait a moment; it had an engine fault.

Initially I thought the drone did it, but later they say it's unrelated:

> 'I already know the ship's called the Furious Purpose and it's back here unscheduled, in Dock 807b. If it's a mechanical problem it's got, I can't imagine it's anything to do directly with the scarring.

Oh I forgot about this:

> Shortly thereafter the Problem Child developed an engine fault - something almost unheard of, even back then - and had to leave the star and the artifact.

So it's the Excession's fault?  It just does that to get ships to leave it alone?  Or it's trying to slow them down for some reason?

Comment: My interpretation was that the Excession mucked with it. Basically a 'go away'

Comment: Like @Valorum I think it is heavily implied that this was the Excession; either deliberately or simply as a side-effect of its presence. This isn't stated outright, but it does affect engine function later in the book and as you note there isn't a credible alternative explanation.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the engine fault on GSV *Problem Child* was a result of the offensive action you describe above (being completely unable to penetrate the artifact with its sensors).

Comment: @Kevin The *Furious Purpose* is the ship with the engine fault